# How to reduce internal extra spacing in a string in python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to store the following info in a python list but the strip function isnt working

```
u'Studio', u'5', u'550.00 SqFt', u'No', u'Agent', u'Quarterly', u'Mediterranean Buildings (38-107)', u'Central A/C & Heating\n                                                                , \n                                                            \n                                                                Balcony\n                                                                , \n                                                            \n                                                                Shared Pool\n                                                                , \n                                                            \n                                                                Built in Wardrobes\n                                                                , \n                                                            \n                                                                Security\n                                                                , \n                                                            \n                                                                View of Landmark', u'']
```

Comment: there are huge amount of spaces between the amenities such as Central heating etc

Comment: Uhm, can you fix that code please? Indent it by 4 spaces to format it as code (or select it and press the `{}` button in the toolbar / or press CTRL+K).

Comment: `strip` only removes spaces at the start and end of the string, not internal spacing within the string.

Comment: how to remove internal then?

Comment: what internal? the code you pasted is a tuple of unicode (yet I don't know what that ']' at the end is used for). do you want to eliminate the whitespaces inside the unicode strings?

Comment: @AhmedMukhtar What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove internal spaces from string by regular expression:

```
import re
text_result = re.sub('\s+',' ', text_input)
```

*EDIT:*

You can even apply this function to every item in your list:

```
list_result = [re.sub("\s+", " ",x) for x in list_input]
```

Comment: for name, value in zip(spans_others, strongs_others):
      if name=="Listed by:":
       break
      else:
       print name.strip(), value.strip()

Comment: i am using this. can u integrate your code with this please

Comment: add lines before your code - just assign your zip list to list_input, add line in my answer for lists and then use list_result in your code instead of zip(..)

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of strings (which you have left the opening brace off of).

You have one *really* ungainly string in index 7 of that list.

You just need to clean that one up.  So:

```
li = [u'Studio', u'5', u'550.00 SqFt', u'No', u'Agent', u'Quarterly', u'Mediterranean Buildings (38-107)', u'Central A/C & Heating\n                                                                , \n                                                            \n                                                                Balcony\n                                                                , \n                                                            \n                                                                Shared Pool\n                                                                , \n                                                            \n                                                                Built in Wardrobes\n                                                                , \n                                                            \n                                                                Security\n                                                                , \n                                                            \n                                                                View of Landmark', u'']

', '.join([line.strip(', ') for line in li[7].splitlines() if line.strip(' ,')])
Out[35]: 'Central A/C & Heating, Balcony, Shared Pool, Built in Wardrobes, Security, View of Landmark'
```

`strip` accepts an iterable of characters to strip off both ends of a given string; I've told it to remove spaces and commas.  Then we rejoin that into a string.

If you need to do this for *every* line in `li`, just do the above in a list comp:

```
[', '.join([line.strip(', ') for line in x.splitlines() if line.strip(' ,')]) for x in li]
```

At this point I would generally go back and re-write whatever code generated this list of clunky strings, since it's cleaner to simply fix the problem before it gets this far.

Answer (score 0):

the strip functions helps you to do something like

```
uns=' this line has extra white spaces '
strv=uns.strip()
#str now has 'this line has extra white spaces'
```

if you want to store striped string to a list you can iterate the list like this

```
pos=0
while pos < len(thelist):
    thevalue=thelist[pos]
    cleanvalue=thevalue.strip()
    thelist[pos]=cleanvalue 
    pos+=1

print thelist
```

whit this every element in the list is striped from extra spaces at the beginning and at the end.

Regards